# 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable django celery beat

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I have Django Celery and Beat on my Docker based setup. My settings are divided into their concerned environment. `base.py` holds the common configurations that are required by both `staging.py` and `production.py`. In my `common.py` I am initialising a variable something like this

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

est_timezone = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))
```

This is the traceback I get for it

```
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-09 10:59:46,845: CRITICAL/MainProcess] beat raised exception <class 'TypeError'>: TypeError("'datetime.datetime' object is not callable")
```

you can put the above snippet in a shell and it works well, so I have no idea what's going on.

This is where the est_timezone variable is being used

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'fetch_rates_on_weekdays': {
        'task': 'where the task at',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=CELERY_TIME_FOR_FETCH_RATES_ON_WEEKENDS, day_of_week='1-5',
                            nowfun=est_timezone)
    }
}
```

traceback

```
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,058: CRITICAL/MainProcess] beat raised exception <class 'AttributeError'>: AttributeError("module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'")
celery-beat_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 41, in __get__
celery-beat_1  |     return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
celery-beat_1  | KeyError: 'scheduler'
celery-beat_1  |
celery-beat_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
celery-beat_1  |
celery-beat_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 105, in start_scheduler
celery-beat_1  |     service.start()
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 618, in start
celery-beat_1  |     humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 43, in __get__
celery-beat_1  |     value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 662, in scheduler
celery-beat_1  |     return self.get_scheduler()
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 657, in get_scheduler
celery-beat_1  |     lazy=lazy,
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 497, in __init__
celery-beat_1  |     Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 253, in __init__
celery-beat_1  |     self.setup_schedule()
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 540, in setup_schedule
celery-beat_1  |     self.merge_inplace(self.app.conf.beat_schedule)
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 450, in merge_inplace
celery-beat_1  |     entry = self.Entry(**dict(b[key], name=key, app=self.app))
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 124, in __init__
celery-beat_1  |     self.last_run_at = last_run_at or self.default_now()
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 128, in default_now
celery-beat_1  |     return self.schedule.now() if self.schedule else self.app.now()
celery-beat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 67, in now
celery-beat_1  |     return (self.nowfun or self.app.now)()
celery-beat_1  |   File "/app/app/settings/common.py", line 146, in est_timezone
celery-beat_1  |     return datetime.now(pytz.timezon('EST'))
celery-beat_1  | AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,059: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,059: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 41, in __get__
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,059: WARNING/MainProcess] return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,059: WARNING/MainProcess] KeyError
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,059: WARNING/MainProcess] :
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,059: WARNING/MainProcess] 'scheduler'
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] sys.exit(main())
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] sys.exit(_main())
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 213, in main
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,060: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,061: WARNING/MainProcess] rv = self.invoke(ctx)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,061: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,061: WARNING/MainProcess] return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,061: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,061: WARNING/MainProcess] return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,061: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] return callback(*args, **kwargs)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 132, in caller
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/beat.py", line 72, in beat
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] return beat().run()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 77, in run
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] self.start_scheduler()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 105, in start_scheduler
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] service.start()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,062: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 618, in start
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 43, in __get__
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 662, in scheduler
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.get_scheduler()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 657, in get_scheduler
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] lazy=lazy,
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 497, in __init__
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,063: WARNING/MainProcess] Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 253, in __init__
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] self.setup_schedule()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 540, in setup_schedule
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] self.merge_inplace(self.app.conf.beat_schedule)
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 450, in merge_inplace
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] entry = self.Entry(**dict(b[key], name=key, app=self.app))
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 124, in __init__
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] self.last_run_at = last_run_at or self.default_now()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 128, in default_now
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,064: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.schedule.now() if self.schedule else self.app.now()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,065: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 67, in now
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,065: WARNING/MainProcess] return (self.nowfun or self.app.now)()
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,065: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/app/app/settings/common.py", line 146, in est_timezone
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,065: WARNING/MainProcess] return datetime.now(pytz.timezon('EST'))
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,065: WARNING/MainProcess] AttributeError
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,065: WARNING/MainProcess] :
celery-beat_1  | [2021-04-12 07:44:58,065: WARNING/MainProcess] module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'
```

Comment: Probably there is somewhere in your code a variable you named as datetime?

Comment: can you post the full traceback?

Comment: The error is  not on variable assignment, its from where u are calling est_timezone in your code.

Comment: @SergeyPugach no there isn't anyother variable named `datetime` I already looked for that.

Comment: @Neeraj i have added where the variable is being called

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for Celery nowfun expects a callable function, while you are passing a datetime object. [Celery Doc](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html)

> nowfun (Callable) – Function returning the current date and time as a
> class:~datetime.datetime.

So in that case you can simply change your est_timezone into a function:

```
def est_timezone():
    return datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))
```

Your schedule crontab will stay the same.

Comment: Tried that, earlier the `est_timezone` was a lambda function, tried your method as well, still won't work, same  `module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'` error. added the entire stacktrace in my question as well

Comment: it's not the same error, earlier it wasnt callable. @Sahil

Comment: @Sahil and this error might be because of wrong imports in the file. You can try import datetime,  and then use datetime.datetime.now.  OR from datetime import datetime as dt,  and use dt.now.